# The value of button.rect() never changed no matter how I moved the button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've set the button to move to the point (100, 65), so I guess (100, 65) should be the button's top-left corner point, but it's not. The output remained `PyQt4.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 30)`, why? Shouldn't it be `PyQt4.QtCore.QRect(100, 65, 100, 30)`?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button.move(100, 65)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 150)
        print "In Window", self.button.rect()
        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From doc:

> This property holds the internal geometry of the widget excluding any window frame.
>
> The rect property equals `QRect(0, 0, width(), height())`.
>
> See the Window Geometry documentation for an overview of geometry issues with windows.
>
> By default, this property contains a value that depends on the user's platform and screen geometry.

It is normal for `QRect()`, so you should use `geometry()`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#rect-prop

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`QWidget::geometry`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) for the problem you have.